# A question about focus

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

Let`s say I have redecorated my living room, it is finished and it looks nice. Someone comments on it, says it looks great. 
Is it possible for me to say: "yes, I have been redecorating", even though it is finished and the focus is on the room? Or do I have to say: "I have redecorated it"?

Comment: why the downvote? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"yes, I have been redecorating" is a completely normal response.  The context is provided by the comment so it is 100% obvious that you have been redecorating *the living room".  The meaning of "I've been ..." is that a action that took some time (a continuous tense) but has effects in the present (a perfect tense).  That fits this exactly.

Comment: So I can use the continuous even if the redecorating has been completed?

Comment: Yes.  The perfect tense indicates "completion".  The continuous indicates that it took an extendi time in the past.